# Android send extra data when menu button pressed

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that needs specific data sent to it. So when the user presses the activity in the menu, I need to send an extra string with it so my code at the moment is:

```
    public static boolean createMenu(SherlockActivity aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = aActivity.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
}
```

So how would I send extra data to my instructionsActivity? I know I use something like `putExtra`, but I can't figure out how to do it with this certain code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Would I create a seperate intent and just pass this into `setIntent` as follows:

```
Intent i = new intent(aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");
```

and then pass the intent into `setIntent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to pass data in Intent, you may want to replace the below

```
menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class));
```

WITH

```
Intent intent = new Intent( aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class );
intent.putExtra( EXTRAS_KEY, extras );
menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(intent);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi I've just implemented it now, and working fine thanks, one question I have is i pass in aActivity which is an activity, but I want it to be generic so I can pass in a listActivity, a fragmentActivity, etc, how can I pass in a generic object as a parameter?

Comment: Do I just pass in an object?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent instruction = new Intent(aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
instruction.putExtra(Extra,"Extra Data");
menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(instruction);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Intent i = new intent(aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
i.putExtras("Flag", "firstInstructions");
i.putExtras("Flag2", "firstInstructions2");
i.putExtras("Flag3", "firstInstructions3");
```

Hope this helps.. :)